# If/else SQL based upon variable result

Tags: php, sql, variables, if-statement

I am trying to update one of two tables within my DB, based upon the results of a variable.  Essentially, the variable is either "a" or "b", based upon the form selection.  I define this variable as $t. I have defined the other variables as well.  Here is the code:

```
$t = $_POST['t']; //(defined in javascript from form selection)
$a = "a";
$b = "b";
//Create own rows in table based upon $t type
if ($t = $a){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_a (id, email, user_type, name, create_time) 
            VALUES ('$db_id','$e','$a','$n', now())";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_b (id, email, user_type, name, create_time) 
            VALUES ('$db_id','$e','$b','$n', now())";   
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
exit();
}
```

I have some coding before this, however I don't think that is the issue, as I can update both tables. I can only update table "a", and not table "b".  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a value to `$t` instead of comparing the variable values, so your if statement will allways evaluate to true.

Change

```
if ($t = $a)
```

to

```
if ($t == $a)
```

As a obligatory sidenote, your query is wide wide open to sql injection, you should use [prepared statements instead](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: I just tried that and it still is not working.  This is driving me insane.  I can't see how this doesn't work.  I have checked syntax and spelling 1000x and that's not it.  I guess I am more frustrated that it will update "a", but not "b".  I tried switching the SQL commands around ("b" before "a") as well as 'if ($t == $v)', but it doesn't work.

Comment: And sorry, I am learning and just am frustrated that I can't figure this out.  Thanks for the help and I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: can you please echo out `$t` before the if. How sure are you that it isn't a?

Comment: GOT IT!  I did have some code that I think may have caused it, but also, I was using an apostrophe in the name for "b" and it wasn't uploading to the database.  THANK YOU MICHAEL!!!!   By the way, why is it I cannot upload an apostrophe to the database?  I have VARCHAR selected.  Is there another format to use for capturing text that covers more characters?